# separate vimrc into two file?

Tags: vim

I'm going to upload my vimrc to githug. But some settings is not general(e.g. on slower machine I dont use cursorcolumn)

So I don't want to put all my settings in one file. How to do this? Is there something like 'source' in bash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a `source` command in `vim`

```
:so[urce] {file}    
        Read Ex commands from {file}.  These are commands that
        start with a ":".
        Triggers the |SourcePre| autocommand.
```

Answer (score 2):

to avoid errors if the file doesn't exist surround it with `if filereadable`.
I have generalized and shared my vimrc and have a line that sources a .vimrc.loc in the users home directory to allow for customization by people that use my vimrc.

```
if filereadable($HOME."/.vimrc.loc")
    source ${HOME}/.vimrc.loc
endif
```